# In Firefox + Adblock Plus, is there a way to block auto-playing videos ONLY on specific websites, from specific domains, etc.?

Tags: firefox, adblock, advertisements, autoplay

In Firefox + Adblock Plus, is there a way to block auto-playing videos *only* on specific websites, from specific domains, etc.?  In general, sites that use auto-play abuse it, but some may be reluctant to shut it off for the entire web browser.

Pertaining to shutting it off in general though, there's already a way to do that which is built in to Firefox and which is documented [here](https://www.ghacks.net/2016/05/06/how-to-stop-auto-playing-videos/).  This is a universal setting though, and it would be nice to be able to specify specific domains and things of that nature.

For the scope of this question, doing this in either Firefox or in the Firefox version of Adblock Plus would work.  (Adblock is fairly popular and standard for this sort of thing anyway, but otherwise, this is ***not*** asking for another plugin that would help.)

Answer (score 1):

This new addon called [Disable HTML5 Autoplay](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/disable-autoplay/?src=search) looks promising. You configure autoplay and auto-buffering on a per-domain basis. It's also WebExtensions-compatible so it's not going to get broken in the next few Firefox updates. I've tested it on YouTube and it works like a charm. I might keep this installed myself!